# Gradle ShadowJar jar of jars without unzipping classes

Tags: gradle

I am trying to create a jar of jars without unzipping class files from each jar. Unfortunately shadowJar unzip's all jars and resulting jars contain directories instead of jars.
My build.gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

dependencies {
 compile("ldapjdk:ldapjdk:1.0"){
     transitive = false
 }

 compile("support:activemq-core:5.3.1"){
     transitive = false
 }

 compile("support:concurrent:0.0"){
     transitive = false
 }

 compile("dom4j:dom4j:${dom4j_version}"){
     transitive = false
 }

 compile("commons-lang:commons-lang:${commons_lang_version}") {
    transitive = false
 }

}


task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {

from(project(':server').configurations.runtime) 
include 'commons-lang2*'
include 'ldapjdk*'
include 'dom4j*'
include 'concurrent*'

}

task copyFiles(dependsOn: [copyRuntimeLibs])


task copyToLib( type: Copy ) {

    into "$buildDir/lib"
    from configurations.runtime

}

jar { dependsOn copyToLib }

shadowJar {

    zip64 true
    baseName = "service"
    from("$buildDir/lib") {
        include '**'
    }

}
```

I've tried from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }. This also extracts classes, MANIFEST, etc.

Is there a way to not extract classes from each jar & instead make a jar of jars?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see this GitHub issue.
https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/111

It is actually not solved yet in the Shadow plugin, there some workarounds are shown there.